# Occupation times for two-state Markov processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, markov-chains

Consider a two-state Markov process in continuous time, with states labelled $A$ and $B$. The transition rates for going from state $A$ to $B$, and state $B$ to $A$ are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively. We are interested in the quantity $p_t(A,x,t_A|A)$, which denotes the probability that, at time $t$, the Markov process is in state $A$, has made a total of $x$ jumps, and has spent time equal to $t_A$ in state $A$, given that it started from state $A$.

I was thinking of two approaches (and both are likely to be equivalent). But I seem to be running into hurdles in both of them, and would be grateful for some help.

My first approach was to write a set of coupled recurrence relations in the following way:
\begin{align}
p_t(A,x,t_A|A) &= \int_0^t e^{-\alpha t'}\cdot \alpha \cdot p_{t-t'}(A,x-1,t_A-t'|B)\cdot dt'\\
p_t(A,x,t_A|B) &= \int_0^t e^{-\beta t'}\cdot \beta \cdot p_{t-t'}(A,x-1,t_A|A)\cdot dt'
\end{align}
The basic idea behind the above equations is that the first jump takes place at time $t'$, and thus, the rest of the $x-1$ jumps have to be made in the remaining $t-t'$ amount of time. Similarly, depending on what the initial state was, the time needed to be spent in state $A$ in the remaining $t-t'$ time is stated in the argument (e.g. if the first $t'$ amount of time was spent in state $A$, then in the remaining amount of time, only $t_A-t'$ amount of time needs to be spent there). There is a minor issue here that the above equation does not necessarily restrict the possibility of $t'>t_A$, which is unphysical. But that can be taken care of by changing the upper limit of the integral in the first equation to $t_A$.

Naively, one would expect that taking a Laplace transform of the two equations with respect to $t$ should simplify matters a lot. For the second equation, it indeed does, as the equation is a simple convolution in $t$. However, the first is not **(please correct me if I am wrong)** and thus, naive Laplace transform with respect to $t$ might not be helpful. Is there any other approach which makes the problem easier?

My second approach was to derive the differential equation satisfied by the quantity $p_t(A,x,t_A|A)$, by working in discrete time-steps of $\Delta t$, and finally taking the limit $\Delta t \to 0$:

\begin{align}
p_{t+\Delta t}(A,x,t_A|A) = p_t(A,x,t_A-\Delta t|A)\cdot (1-\alpha \Delta t) + p_t(B,x-1,t_A-\Delta t|A)\cdot \beta \Delta t 
\end{align}
which upon rearranging gives us
\begin{align}
\frac{p_{t+\Delta t}(A,x,t_A|A) - p_{t}(A,x,t_A- \Delta t|A)}{\Delta t} = -\alpha\cdot p_t(A,x,t_A-\Delta t|A) + \beta \cdot p_t(B,x-1,t_A - \Delta t|A).
\end{align}
In the limit of $\Delta t \to 0$, we get:
$$\frac{\partial{p_{t}(A,x,t_A|A)}}{\partial{t}}+\frac{\partial{p_{t}(A,x,t_A|A)}}{\partial{t_A}} = -\alpha\cdot p_t(A,x,t_A|A) + \beta \cdot p_t(B,x-1,t_A|A). $$

Similarly, one could write equations for $p_t(B,x,t_A|A)$. Here (again naively), it seems like one could take a Laplace transform with respect to $t$ and $t_A$, and define a generating function for $x$ to simplify the problem. However, one thing that scares me is that $t_A$ cannot take any value. It must always take values less than $t$. Thus, independently taking Laplace transforms with respect to $t$ and $t_A$ seems shady.

Is there a way to overcome one (or both) of the hurdles?

Comment: Did you try to calculate these functions using your recurrence for $x=1,2,3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let the final time to be $t=1$ (if it is not, we can make it so by rescaling time as $\alpha'=t\alpha$ and $\beta'=t\alpha$).

Then, consider a single trajectory of the process that starts and ends on state $A$ and makes $x$ jumps ($x$ has to be even). We can represent any such trajectory in terms of the jump times, $$\vec{t}=(t_{0}=0\le t_{1}\le\dots\le t_{x}\le1) \tag{1}$$
The conditional probability of the trajectory is given by the product of the jump probabilities, multiplied by the probability of not leaving state $A$ after the last jump:
$$p(\vec{t}\vert A)=e^{-\alpha(1-t_{x})}\prod_{i=0}^{x-1}p_{i}(t_{i+1}\vert t_{i}).\tag{2}$$
We will assume below that $x\ge 2$ (otherwise $t_A=1$ and $p(A,x,t_A|A)=e^{-\alpha}$).

Now, if $i$ is even, then the jump at $t_{i+1}$ is from state $A$ to state $B$ and has probability density $p_{i}(t_{i+1}\vert t_{i})=\alpha e^{-(t_{i+1}-t_{i})\alpha}$. Otherwise the jump is from state $B$ to state $A$ and has probability density $p_{i}(t_{i+1}\vert t_{i})=\beta e^{-(t_{i+1}-t_{i})\beta}$. Plugging into  $(2)$ and simplifying gives
$$p(\vec{t}\vert A)=e^{-[t_{A}(\vec{t})\alpha+(1-t_{A}(\vec{t}))\beta]}\alpha^{x/2}\beta^{x/2}\tag{3},$$
where $t_A(\vec{t})$ indicates the amount of time that trajectory $\vec{t}$ spends in state $A$.

To get your answer, we integrate over the set of all ordered sequences $\vec{t}$ that obey $(1)$ and spend $t_A$ time in state $A$, which we indicate as $\Omega$. This gives:
\begin{align}P(A,x,t_{A}\vert A)=\int_{\Omega}p(\vec{t}\vert A)d\vec{t}=e^{-[t_{A}\alpha+(1-t_{A})\beta]}\alpha^{x/2}\beta^{x/2}\int_{\Omega} d\vec{t}.\tag{4}\end{align}

It remains to calculate the volume of $\Omega$.  Let us indicate this set as
$$\Omega=\{t\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{x}:0\le t_{1}\le\dots t_{x}\le1,\sum_{i=1}^{x/2}t_{2i}-t_{2i-1}=1-t_{A}\}$$
Note that $\Omega$ has the same volume as the following subset of the unit $x$-simplex:
$$\Omega'=\{g\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{x+1}:\sum_{i=1}^{x+1} g_{i}=1,\sum_{i=1}^{x/2}g_{2i}=1-t_{A}\},$$
which follows from the simple transformation $g_{i}=t_{i}-t_{i-1}$ for $i=1..x+1$ (where $t_0=0$ and $t_{x+1}=1$). Then, by rearranging the odd and even coordinates, it is easy to see that $\Omega'$ is itself a cross product of two scaled unit simplices:
$$\Omega'=\{g\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{x/2+1}:\sum_{i=1}^{x/2+1}g_{i}=t_{A}\}\times\{g\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{x/2}:\sum_{i=1}^{x/2} g_{i}=1-t_{A}\}$$
The volume of $\Omega'$ is the product of the volumes of these simplices,
$$\mathrm{Vol}(\Omega') =\mathrm{Vol}(\Omega) = \frac{t_{A}^{x/2}}{(x/2)!}\frac{(1-t_{A})^{x/2-1}}{(x/2-1)!}$$
Combined with $(4)$ this gives
\begin{align}P(A,x,t_{A}\vert A)=e^{-[t_{A}\alpha+(1-t_{A})\beta]}\alpha^{x/2}\beta^{x/2}\frac{t_{A}^{x/2}}{(x/2)!}\frac{(1-t_{A})^{x/2-1}}{(x/2-1)!}.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer -- I was fairly convinced by your logic. However, I am slightly concerned about the final two steps. When you integrate over all $\Omega$ (all admissible combinations of $t_1, t_2, \dots, t_x$), aren't you integrating over all $t_A$ also? So perhaps $\Omega$ should be restricted in such a way, that $t_A$ remains a constant. 

I have been trying a different approach to the problem, and will post my solution shortly.

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic I think you are absolutely right, my original answer was not correct because I integrated over $t_A$ -- apologies. However, I think there is a simple fix, which is to represent the set of "constrained" trajectories (where each trajectory is required to spend time $t_A$ in state $A$) is written as a cross product of two simplices. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! Just one more thing -- we do not want to compute the volume of these simplices, right? Rather, we want their surface area. For example, if we take $x=3$, then we have $g_1,g_2,g_3$ and $g_4$ such that $g_1+g_3=t_A$ and $g_2+g_4=1-t_A$. Now, we are not interested in the area of the right angled triangle formed by the $g_1$ and $g_3$ axes, and the line $g_1+g_3=t_A$. Instead, we want the length of the line with endpoints $(0,t_A)$ and $(t_A,0)$, because that defines the number of ways $g_1$ and $g_3$ can be distributed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Perhaps we will need to use this result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996038/area-of-standard-simplex

Comment: @StatisticalMechanic I don't think your counterexample works, as $x$ has to be even for the trajectory to end on state A. Instead, let us take $x=2$ as an example. Then, $g_1+g_3=t_A$ and $g_2=1-t_A$, and the volume of $\Omega'$ is given by the volume of a simplex with two vertices (i.e., a line) and a simplex with one vertex (i.e., a point), as expected.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion and for dragging this conversation. I did not mean to provide a counterexample. Instead, I just wanted to understand the idea behind computing the volume of the simplex. My concern is that the formula $\frac{t_A^{x/2}}{(x/2)!}$ that you are using is for the volume defined by $\Delta=\{g\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{x/2+1}:\sum_{i=0}^{x/2} g_{2i+1} \leq t_{A}\}$ whereas we want the volume of $\Delta_1=\{g\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{x/2+1}:\sum_{i=0}^{x/2} g_{2i+1} = t_{A}\}$ (the surface area of the simplex).

Comment: So, in the example with $x=2$, the relevant volume of simplex defined by $g_1 + g_3 = t_A$ should be $\sqrt{2}~t_A$, and not $t_A^{2/2}/(2/2)! = t_A$. This also makes sense, as $\sqrt{2}~t_A$ gives us the length of the line joining $(0,t_A)$ and $(t_A,0)$, on which all the allowed values of $(g_1,g_3)$ lie.

Comment: I used that the volume of the probability -simplex $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}_+:\sum_i x_i =1\}$ is $1/n!$ (you can check e.g. by running Integrate[DiracDelta[x1+x2-1],{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1}] in Mathematica). Let's think about the example with two jumps, whose times are given by $t_1$ and $t_2$. The first jump can occur at any time between 0 and $t_A$, and the timing of the second jump is then fixed by the condition $t_1+(1-t_2)=t_A$. So the volume of Ω is given by integrating over the set $t_1\in[0,t_A]$, which has volume $t_A$